# Why can't tracking references be used as class members?

Tags: c++-cli, tracking-reference

The following code:

```
ref class A
{
private:
  int% referenceToAnInt;
};
```

produces the following error in Visual Studio:

error C3160: 'int %' : a data member of a managed class cannot have this type

I thought tracking references were a managed thing - so why can't they be a member of a managed class?
Also: How would I store a reference to a value type in C++/CLI correctly?

Comment: Please, try to ask one question at a time. If you have two different questions, ask them in two posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CLR doesn't allow storing tracking references as fields. Also, from the C++/CLI-Spec:

> A program containing a tracking reference that has storage duration
>   other than automatic is ill-formed. (This precludes having a tracking
>   reference as a data member.)

I guess they wanted to avoid the problem where you keep a reference longer than the actual lifetime of the referenced object. An alternative would be to use a wrapper ref class to hold the value, or delegates for reading / writing.

Answer (score 2):

Tracking references *are* “managed thing” which is why you can't use them as a member of a class. They are similar to C++ `&` references in that you can use them to refer to local variables in some other method. But local variables are stored in the short term store (a.k.a. the stack). That means that when the method that contains that local variable ends, the reference wouldn't be valid anymore, but the object could still exist.

This would not be memory-safe, which is why doing this is forbidden in .Net.

Comment: C++/CLI does not enforce safety, unless you use the `/clr:safe` switch to produce verifiable output.

Comment: C++/CLI does not, but CLR in this case does.